# FileDialog filter not updating when changing selection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, filedialog

I have a simple issue. I have a filedialog in a wpf application. Things works fine when I run the application for the first time. But when I change the file extension, and change back, I dont see anything.

This is the code:

```
Filedlg.FileName = "*.msr"; // Default file name
Filedlg.DefaultExt = ".msr"; // Default file extension
Filedlg.Filter = "Raw (.msr)| *.msr | All files |*.*" ; // Filter files by extension
```

I see .msr files. Then I choose to see all files and then switch back to .msr extension. But I dont see any files.

Thoughts?

Kindly ask details if required.

Comment: Could it be because of the extra space in `(.msr)| *.msr`?

Comment: no. But it was extra space between | All files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filedlg.Filter = "Raw (*.msr)|*.msr|All Files(*.*)|*.*";

this one works. Problem was extra space between | All.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Filter` property, `DefaultExt` gets ignored or in worst case can cause issues. You need to use `FilterIndex` instead to mark default extension. You can find out more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filterindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I would also skip setting file name to *.msr.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Filedlg.Filter =  "Raw (.msr)| *.msr |" + "All Files(*.*)|*.*";
```